# Dynamically loaded nested component Angular 9

Tags: angular, angular9

I have been referring this.
https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

I want the content to be send by the server , which contains html code with ng-template 
`<ng-template ad-host></ng-template>`.

My content from server may look like

```
                  <div class="ad-banner-example">
                    <h3>Advertisements</h3>
                    <ng-template ad-host></ng-template> <!-- one entry of ad-host -->
                    <div class="content">
                        <!-- all other content --> 
                        <ng-template ad-host></ng-template>  <!-- another ad-host -->
                  </div>
```

I modified the ad-banner.component.ts as follows.

```js
import {
      Component,
      Input,
      OnInit,
      ViewChild,
      ComponentFactoryResolver,
      OnDestroy,
      ViewContainerRef
    } from '@angular/core';

    import { AdDirective } from './ad.directive';
    import { AdItem }      from './ad-item';
    import { AdComponent } from './ad.component';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-ad-banner',
      template: `<div [innerHTML]="inerhtml"></div>` // REPLACED THIS WITH inerhtml, 
    })
    export class AdBannerComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy  {
      @Input() ads: AdItem[];
      currentAdIndex = -1;
      @ViewChild(AdDirective, {static: true}) adHost: AdDirective;

      @ViewChild(AdBannerComponent, {read: ViewContainerRef}) other;

      ViewContainerRef
      interval: any;
      inerhtml = `<div class="ad-banner-example">
        <h3>Advertisements</h3>
        <ng-template ad-host></ng-template>
    </div>`;

      constructor(private viewContainerRef:ViewContainerRef,private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

      ngOnInit() {
        // Imagine server sending this response. I will Do this part, once this work
        this.inerhtml=`  <div class="ad-banner-example">
                    <h3>Advertisements</h3>
                    <ng-template ad-host></ng-template>
                  </div>`;
        this.loadComponent();
        this.getAds();
      }

      ngOnDestroy() {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
      }

      loadComponent() {
        this.currentAdIndex = (this.currentAdIndex + 1) % this.ads.length;
        const adItem = this.ads[this.currentAdIndex];

        const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(adItem.component);

        const viewContainerRef = this.adHost.viewContainerRef;
        viewContainerRef.clear();

        const componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
        (<AdComponent>componentRef.instance).data = adItem.data;
      }

      getAds() {
        this.interval = setInterval(() => {
          this.loadComponent();
        }, 3000);
      }
    }
```

But this code wont render the view, I can only see The Header Advertisements on the screen. I am new please help.

[Here is the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nad9ty-hfutsz)

Comment: You define one ng-template and include it at different locations using ng-container. Also it's a bad idea in general to send html from backend although if it's dynamic cms content created via wysiwyg then no other option

Comment: @muasif80 , It is a dynamic cms content created , thats what I am looking for. Thanks this what I am looking for.

Comment: Why can't you just show the content as innerHTML?

Comment: @MarcelHoekstra , is what exactly doing, but the ad-host component needs to render; dynamic content here from server

Comment: But what would you miss if you replace: <ng-template ad-host></ng-template> by <div [innerHTML]="myServerHtml"></div>

Comment: @MarcelHoekstra, I see your point. But what I want is my server will send html code that  contains angular directives and the angular application will render the corresponding component / directive ( which browser already has). This way I will not send a huge bunch of html code.